# In ps -ef, what information does the fourth column show?

Tags: linux, shell, ps

For example,

```
ps -ef

Display full information about each of the processes currently running.

UID PID PPID C STIME TTY TIME CMD
hope 29197 18961 0 Sep27 ? 00:00:06 sshd: hope@pts/87
hope 32097 29197 0 Sep27 pts/87 00:00:00 -csh
hope 7209 32097 0 12:17 pts/87 00:00:00 ps -ef
```

What information does the column named **C** provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `ps(1)` manpage, **STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS** section:

```
c          C        processor utilization. Currently, this is the integer
                    value of the percent usage over the lifetime of the
                    process. (see %cpu).
```